# Getting a list from ArrayList throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I created a list containing lists of integers. I figured out the issue,it's because my `recipe` (outer list) is empty.

**My code:**

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt(); // t=4
        List<List<Integer>> recipe = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(t+1);
        for(int i=1 ; i<t+1 ; i++){
            for (int l = 1; l <= 4; l++) { 
                recipe.get(l).add(i);  
            }
        }
```

To fix it, all I can think of is this,

```
for(int i= 0; i<t+1 ;i++){
    recipe.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Like when an `Array` is created, you can call any index.

Comment: "I figured out the issue,it's because my recipe (outer list) is empty. " what issue??

Comment: `recipe.get(l)` line 6 in code throws IndexOutOfBounds error.

Comment: "what do you think `new ArrayList(size)` does" - "Same thing what 'array' does" no, arrays are filled with default elements: `0` `false` `null`, but in case of collections you are setting initial capacity of its inner structure, not size of collection. `recipe.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());` is proper solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with your code.

Firstly, the `int` in `ArrayList`'s constructor only specifies the initial capacity.

It doesn't initialize its elements.

In turn, in your inner loop, you forget to initialize them before referencing them.

Finally, your reference is 1-indexed, while in both arrays and collections it should be 0-indexed.

Here's a corrected version of your code.

```
int t = 4; // bypassing the Scanner here
// initialize outer list with initial capacity 5
List<List<Integer>> recipe = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(t+1);
for(int i=1 ; i<t+1 ; i++){
    // initializes inner list
    recipe.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    // careful, you're using a different control variable to access the list elements
    for (int l = 1; l <= 4; l++) {     
        // collections are 0-indexed, hence l - 1
        recipe.get(l - 1).add(i);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a new inner ArrayList in each iteration of the inner loop makes no sense. You would be adding t*4 inner `ArrayList`s to the `recipe` List and only add data to the first 4 of them.

Answer (score 1):

`new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(t+1)` creates an empty `ArrayList` with an initial capacity of `t+1`. You must add an element to the List before you can access it.

In addition, the indices of the List are 0 based.

```
    for(int i=0 ; i<t ; i++){
        recipe.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) { 
            recipe.get(i).add(l);  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the inner loop iteration is a constant(i.e., 4 in your example) you can directly assign it like

```
int t=4;
List<List<Integer>> recipe = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(t+1);
for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
    recipe.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1,2,3,4})));
}
```

**Java 8**

```
int t=4;
List<List<Integer>> java8Recipie = IntStream.range(0, t)
                 .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(1, t+1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```